# Using C++ keywords in connect signal/slot

Tags: c++, qt, slot

In Qt 5.9, I am trying to use C++ keywords in place of SLOT. Is that possible (without a separate method)?

Something like:

```
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),  this, (delete image_ptr));
```

That is not working, below my code example:

```
QImage *image_ptr = new QImage(3, 3, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
QEventLoop evt;
QFutureWatcher<QString> watcher;
QTimer timer(this);
timer.setSingleShot(true);
QObject::connect(&watcher, &QFutureWatcher<QString>::finished, &evt, &QEventLoop::quit);
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &watcher, SLOT(cancel()));
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),  &evt, SLOT(quit));
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),  this, (delete image_ptr));
QFuture<QString> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&myClass::myMethod,*image_ptr);
watcher.setFuture(future);
timer.start(100);
evt.exec();
```

Comment: Use a lambda. https://artandlogic.com/2013/09/qt-5-and-c11-lambdas-are-your-friend/

Comment: Although with that said this looks dangerous. I mean if the concurrent execution is still running and you free the image bad things will happen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression instead (more about the new connect syntaxis [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)).

Take into consideration that *receiver* in those examples is the-otherwise-owner of the slot (if used the old syntax), it is not a global variable or macro. Also, when using lambdas you don't have access to the `sender()` method, so you must take care of having access to them through other method. To solve those situations you have to capture those variables in the lambda. In your case, it is only the pointer.

```
QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&image_ptr]() { delete image_ptr; });
```

Answer (score 3):

lambda expression in connect sample :

```
connect(
    sender, &Sender::valueChanged,
    [=]( const QString &newValue ) { receiver->updateValue( "senderValue", newValue ); }
);
```